# yarn - Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, hadoop-yarn

I have this problem with Unable to get local issuer certificate.
I already tried `yarn config set strict-ssl false`. I also set proxy. And also tried `npm config set strict-ssl false`, but none of these worked.

It's a Windows Computer with a proxy network.

Hope someone can help me here.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem today, too bad all the answers also don't work for me. I set my certificate files as well and that's not working. I captured the certificates using openssl command for all the different package registries for yarn, npm, github.com, nodejs.org, and all the corporate root certificates in one pem file 
I'm sure I did this wrong, but I've seen nothing useful explaining how to do this end to end